# Segmentation fault while implementing FCFS algorithm from Linux to C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//argv[1]은 태스크
int task[10][4];
struct ready{
    int pid;
    int priority;
    int arrival;
    int burst;
    struct ready* next;
};
struct ready* head = NULL;
int wating[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

void enrqueue(int j)
{
    struct ready* new = (struct ready*)malloc(sizeof(struct ready));
    new->pid = task[j][0];
    new->priority = task[j][1];
    new->arrival = task[j][2];
    new->burst = task[j][3];
    new->next = NULL;
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = new;
        return;
    }
    struct ready* ptr = head;
    while(ptr->next != NULL)
    {
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    ptr->next = new;
}

int derqueue()
{
    struct ready* ptr = head;
    struct ready* prevptr = ptr;
    ptr = ptr->next;
    head = ptr;
    return prevptr->pid;
}

void runfcfs(int time)
{
    int running = 0;
    int idle = 0;
    int j;
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        if(task[j][2] == time)
        {
            idle = 1;
            printf("\n<time %d> [new arrival] process %d", time, task[j][0]);
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if((task[i][2] < time) && (task[i][3] + wating[i]) > time)//이미누가실행중이다
                {
                    enrqueue(j);
                }
            }
        }
        if((task[j][2] < time) && (task[j][3] + wating[j]) == time)
        {
            idle = 1;
            printf("\n<time %d> process %d is finished", time, task[j][0]);
            printf("\n--------------------------(Context-Switch)");
        }
        if((task[j][2] < time) && (task[j][3] + wating[j]) > time)//러닝중일때
        {
            idle = 1;
            if(running == 0)//러닝중인애없을때
            {
                if(head != NULL)//레디큐에있던애가들어오는거라면
                {
                    struct ready* ptr = head;
                    while(ptr->next != NULL);
                    {
                        if(task[j][0] == ptr->pid)
                        {
                            printf("\n<time %d> process %d is runningq", time, derqueue());
                            break;
                        }
                        ptr = ptr->next;
                    }
                    if(ptr->next == NULL)
                    {
                        printf("\n<time %d> process %d is runningnq", time, task[j][0]);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\n<time %d> process %d is running", time, task[j][0]);
                }
            }
            running = 1;
        }
    }
    if(idle == 0)
    {
        printf("\n<time %d> ---- System is idle ----", time);
        return ;
    }
}
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)   
        {
            fscanf(file, "%d", &task[i][j]);//배열의0pid, 1pri, 2arri, 3burst
        }
    }  
    fclose(file);
    wating[0] = task[0][2];
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if(task[i][2] > wating[i])//시작하는시간계산
        {
            wating[i+1] = task[i][2] + task[i][3];
        }
        else if(task[i][2] <= wating[i])
        {
            wating[i+1] = wating[i] + task[i][3];
        }
    }
    printf("Scheduling : FCFS\n");
    printf("========================================\n");
    int t;
    for(t = 0; t <= 53; t++)//t는time
    {
        runfcfs(t);
    }
    printf("\n<time %d> all processes finish", t);
    printf("\n========================================");
}
```

Ouput is:

```
Scheduling : FCFS
========================================
<time 0> ---- System is idle ----
<time 1> [new arrival] process 1
<time 2> process 1 is running
<time 3> process 1 is running 
segmentation fault
```

Why do I get a Segmentation fault here? How can I fix it? Is there a problem with the enrqueue?

Input file of argv[1]:

```
1 10 1 5
2 20 3 3
3 30 8 3
4 20 10 6
5 10 15 1
6 50 21 8
7 80 22 7
8 50 30 4
9 40 40 10
10 60 45 3
```

Comment: Don't recommend using `new` as variable name, as it is a C++ keyword – maybe you ever won't, but *if* you switch the language, this guarantees trouble. You have a memory leak due to not freeing the linked list node on dequeuing.

Comment: `while(ptr->next != NULL);` Did you see the extra `;` ? Note that gcc compiler warns you about that

Comment: Side note: you should check if `argc` is > 1 before `FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");` and you should check if `fopen` succeeds.

Comment: Other side note: `while(ptr->next != NULL)` to find the last node of the list is inefficient. The longer the list the more inefficient it will become. Imagine what happens if your list contains 1'000'000 elements. Google _shlemiel the painter's algorithm_

Comment: Recommendation: Maintain both a head and a tail pointer – this avoids necessity of having to iterate over all the list on inserting new elements. You might want to define a `struct LinkedList { struct ready* head; struct ready* tail; }` which you could then pass to enqueue/dequeue functions, usually as pointer so that modifications of the head/tail pointers, if need be, get visible to outside...

Comment: Adding to previous comment: You shouldn't rely on global variables that much. Especially as the linked list functions access these you won't ever be able to create more than one single linked list. Instead pass the head pointers (and possibly tail, see previous recommendation) as *parameters* to the functions. This way you can have as many linked lists as you want, which improves re-usability tremendously. If you keep the linked list itself as a global – up to you to decide, but the functions shouldn't access it directly.